# SparkSessionExtensions injectFunction in Databricks environment

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, databricks-community-edition

SparkSessionExtensions injectFunction works locally, but I can't get it working in the Databricks environment.

The [itachi](https://github.com/yaooqinn/itachi) project defines Catalyst expressions, like `age` that I can successfully use locally via `spark-sql`:

```
bin/spark-sql --packages com.github.yaooqinn:itachi_2.12:0.1.0 --conf spark.sql.extensions=org.apache.spark.sql.extra.PostgreSQLExtensions
```

```
spark-sql> select age(timestamp '2000', timestamp'1990');
10 years
```

I'm having trouble getting this working in the Databricks environment.

I started up a Databricks community cluster with the `spark.sql.extensions=org.apache.spark.sql.extra.PostgreSQLExtensions` configuration option set.

[image: create cluster]

Then I attached the library.

[image: attach lib]

The `array_append` function that's defined in itachi isn't accessible like I expected it to be:

[image: fail to run function]

Confirm configuration option is properly set:

[image]

spark-alchemy has [another approach](https://github.com/swoop-inc/spark-alchemy/wiki/Spark-Native-Functions) that works in the Databricks environment.  Do we need to mess around with Spark internals to get this working in the Databricks environment?  Or is there a way to get `injectFunction` working in Databricks?

Answer (score 1):

The `spark.sql.extensions` works just fine on full Databricks (until it's going too deep into the internals of the Spark - sometimes there are incompatibilities), but not on Community Edition.  The problem is that `spark.sql.extensions` are called during session initialization, and library specified in UI is installed afterwards, so this happens after/in parallel with initialization.  On full Databricks that's workarounded by using [init script](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/init-scripts.html) to install library before cluster starts, but this functionality is not available on Community Edition.

The workaround would be to register functions explicitly, like this:

```scala
%scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.postgresql.{Age, ArrayAppend, ArrayLength, IntervalJustifyLike, Scale, SplitPart, StringToArray, UnNest}
import org.apache.spark.sql.extra.FunctionAliases

spark.sessionState.functionRegistry.registerFunction(Age.fd._1, Age.fd._2, Age.fd._3)
spark.sessionState.functionRegistry.registerFunction(FunctionAliases.array_cat._1, FunctionAliases.array_cat._2, FunctionAliases.array_cat._3)
spark.sessionState.functionRegistry.registerFunction(ArrayAppend.fd._1, ArrayAppend.fd._2, ArrayAppend.fd._3)
spark.sessionState.functionRegistry.registerFunction(ArrayLength.fd._1, ArrayLength.fd._2, ArrayLength.fd._3)
spark.sessionState.functionRegistry.registerFunction(IntervalJustifyLike.justifyDays._1, IntervalJustifyLike.justifyDays._2, IntervalJustifyLike.justifyDays._3)
spark.sessionState.functionRegistry.registerFunction(IntervalJustifyLike.justifyHours._1, IntervalJustifyLike.justifyHours._2, IntervalJustifyLike.justifyHours._3)
spark.sessionState.functionRegistry.registerFunction(IntervalJustifyLike.justifyInterval._1, IntervalJustifyLike.justifyInterval._2, IntervalJustifyLike.justifyInterval._3)
spark.sessionState.functionRegistry.registerFunction(Scale.fd._1, Scale.fd._2, Scale.fd._3)
spark.sessionState.functionRegistry.registerFunction(SplitPart.fd._1, SplitPart.fd._2, SplitPart.fd._3)
spark.sessionState.functionRegistry.registerFunction(StringToArray.fd._1, StringToArray.fd._2, StringToArray.fd._3)
spark.sessionState.functionRegistry.registerFunction(UnNest.fd._1, UnNest.fd._2, UnNest.fd._3)
```

After that it works:

[image]

It's not so handy as extensions, but that's a limitation of CE.

Comment: So in order to get this working on full Databricks, I need to install the lib via an init script (and not install the lib after the cluster starts)?  Can you please provide a code snippet?  Thanks!

Comment: it's just a shell script that either copies file from DBFS (as `/dbfs/some_location`) or downloads file from internet, and put it into `/databricks/jars`.  See examples here: https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/init-scripts.html#example-cluster-scoped-init-scripts